# Where is the core code that makes up Blender's ShapeKey?

Tags: shape-keys, development, source-code

I'm looking for the core C / C ++ code that makes up Blender's ShapeKey.

I'm looking for Blender standard features, not add-ons.

I know Blender is open source, but I'm an amateur about Blender.

Therefore, I don't know how the Blender code is published.

Is the original Blender code available on GitHub?

If so, where is the code for ShapeKey published?

If possible, I would like to know the location of the C / C ++ code, but if that is not possible, I would like to know the location of Python.

Comment: Blender git https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/ and https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Source/File_Structure

Comment: this question might be better suited for https://devtalk.blender.org/

Comment: C++ development questions are off-topic https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-questions-should-be-definitely-off-topic/6#6

Comment: source/blender/editors/object/object_shapekey.c

Comment: blender/source/blender/blenkernel/intern/key.c

Comment: @Luciano Not *entirely* true: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2216/source-code-questions-in-2016

Comment: @RayMairlot damn, your question beats mine by 3 years! :)